# Call a method based on the object type

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have two helper methods:

```
public String load(URL url) {...}
public String load(File file) {...}
```

I want to have a method that calls the appropriate helper method depending on what object type it receives:

```
public void operate(Object object) {...}
```

I understand that there is a convoluted way of doing it which is:

```
public void operate(Object object) {
    String data = null;
    if (object.getClass().equals(File.class)) {
        data = load((File) object);
    }
    if (object.getClass().equals(URL.class)) {
        data = load((URL) object);
    }
    // operate on the data....
}
```

However, this does not seem elegant and was curious if there was a better way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly less convoluted way is `instanceof`, e.g.

```
if (object instanceof File)) {
    data = load((File) object);
}
```

However, most of the time, using `instanceof` is a sign that there's a better structure for what you're trying to achieve, e.g.

```
public void operate(File file) {
    operate(load(file));
}

public void operate(URL url) {
    operate(load(url));
}

public void operate(String data) {
    // operate on the data....
}
```

Comment: This violates the *Open-Closed* principle. Your class will have to be modified for each new input source.

Comment: No, you can just extend the class with a new `operate(NewInputSourceType)` overload

Comment: But you won't get the advantage of being able to decide at runtime, what source to load the data from with this approach. Overloaded methods are resolved at compile time.

Comment: Correct, this solution only works if the type is known at compile time

Comment: Yes. Polymorphic substitutions is required for OCP. Extending the class and adding new `operate(NewInputSourceType)` overload will not let you polymorphically substitute an implementation. If client code that was loading data from a `File` has to start loading data from `NewInputSourceType` instead, it will have to be changed to use the reference of the class that has this method. What good is a class that adheres to OCP if it requires client code to change for each new technique? OCP should extend to client code as well. See `DataOperator` in my answer which does not change for any input.

Answer (score 8):

> However, this does not seem elegant and was curious if there was a better way.

That's right. This violates the *Open-Closed* principle. A class must be open to extension but closed to modification. You are also correct when you say that you need a generic Object. Here's what you can do :

**Create a Loader interface**

```
public interface Loader<T> {
   public String load(T t);
}
```

**Create a loader for loading from File**

```
public class FileLoader implements Loader<File> {
     public String load(File f) { 
            //load from file 
     }    
}
```

**Create a loader for loading from Url**

```
public class UrlLoader implements Loader<Url> {
     public String load(URL r) { 
            //load from url 
     }    
}
```

**Create a class that operates on the data**

```
 class DataOperator<T> {
    Loader<T> loader;
    public SomeClient(Loader<T> loader) {
       this.loader = loader;
    }

    public void operate(T inputSource) {
       String data = loader.load(inputSource);
       //operate on the data
    }

 }
```

**Client code can then use the above API as shown below :**

```
DataOperator<File> fileDataOperator = new DataOperator<>(new FileLoader());
fileDataOperator.operate(new File("somefile.txt"));

DataOperator<URL> urlDataOperator = new DataOperator<>(new UrlLoader());
urlDataOperator.operate(new URL("http://somesite.com"));
```

You might be thinking that this is a lot of classes for solving a simple problem. However, this is actually inline with the well known *Open-Closed* design principle. Notice how you control what technique is used for loading the data by creating an instance of an appropriate class. Another advantage you get is that you can decide which technique to use at `runtime` by creating a `Factory` that takes user input and creates the appropriate concrete subclass. This is a simplified version of the [**Strategy pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

**Disclaimer :** The code samples presented above have not been tested for compilation errors as I don't have `Java` on this machine.

Comment: Can you also explain how this can be used in the `operate()` method?

Comment: @CupawnTae I have elaborated on what I meant when I said "*In the real world, client code would depend on the `Loader` interface*" in the earlier version of my answer. I hope my elaboration has clarified the point I was making which is inline with what was asked by the OP.

Comment: @Codebender I have elaborated my answer to expand the statement I made earlier "*In the real world, client code would depend on the Loader interface*"

Comment: @CKing odd, I never saw that comment, and don't see it in the edit history - did it get rolled up in a subsequent edit? Anyway, I think your edit makes it clearer

Comment: @CupawnTae I just took a look at the edit history and found that the earlier statement I made is missing. That's strange because I copied that statement into my comment.

Comment: It sometimes rolls multiple edits into one if they're made close together - maybe it did that here? Couple of typos - `URL` should be caps and should be `new URL(...)` on the last line - I won't edit them in in case you're still editing yourself

Answer (score 3):

You can use instanceof and check it and then cast the object and call the method:

```
if (obj instanceof File) {
   ((File) obj).method();
}
else if (obj instanceof URL) {
   ((URL) obj).method();
}
```

or the inverse like:

```
if (obj instanceof File) {
 load((File) obj)
}
else if (obj instanceof URL) {
   load((URL) obj)
}
```

Comment: This violates a very solid (pun intended) design principle known as the open-closed principle. Doesn't matter if you use `equals` or `instanceof`, you have to modify your class every time you want to add a new technique for loading data.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct: casting is necessary but inelegant.

Another way to do this if you like GoF Design Patterns is the Visitor pattern aka double dispatch.

A third way is to use Java reflection.

Comment: I would love it if you could amend your answer to show an example with reflection.

Comment: Sorry, no time.  Why don't you work it out and present it?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on the same problem and found a different approach using Reflection:

```
public void operate(Object object) {
    Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("load", object.getClass());
    String data = (String) method.invoke(this, object);
    // [...]
}
```

Of course, it comes with the burden of handling quite a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Overload the operate-method as well. The use the data which you received to call a method which accepts an String.

```
public static void operate(URL url) {
    String data = load(url);
    doOperations(data);
}

public static void operate(File file) {
    String data = load(file);
    doOperations(data);
}

private static void doOperations(String data) {
    //TODO Do something with data
}
```

Comment: I like this.  It doesn't really cut down on the number of lines of coce, but at least it limits which object types can be passed to operate()